# Get elements with odd length in a Haskell list of strings

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I have a list of strings in Haskell and I need to get those elements with odd length in another list. How can this be done using higher order functions like foldr, foldl, foldr1, foldl1, filter, map, and so on? I will very much appreciate your help. Can list comprehension be used in this case?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are aware that `filter` exists (since you've mentioned), but perhaps are uncertain how it works. If you're trying to extract a specific subset of a list, this seems to be the right path. If you look at its type-signature, you'll find it's pretty straight-forward:

```
(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

That is, it takes a function that returns True or False (i.e. true to contain in the new set, false otherwise) and produces a new list. Similarly, Haskell provides a function called `odd` in Prelude. It's signature looks as follows:

```
Integral a => a -> Bool
```

That is, it can take any `Integral` type and returns True if it is odd, false otherwise.

Now, let's consider a solution:

```
filter odd [1..10]
```

This will extract all the odd numbers between [1,10].

I noticed you mentioned list comprehensions. You probably do not want to use this if you are already given a list and you are simply filtering it. However, a list comprehension would be a perfectly acceptable solution:

```
[x | x <- [1..10], odd x]
```

In general, list comprehensions are used to express the generation of lists with more complicated constraints.

Now, to actually answer your question. Since we know we can filter numbers, and if we're using Hoogle searching for the following type (notice that `String` is simply `[Char]`):

```
[a] -> Int
```

You will see a `length` function. With some function composition, we can quickly see how to create a function which filters odd length. In summary, we have `odd` which is type `Int -> Bool` (in this case) and we have `length` which is `[a] -> Int` or-- specifically-- `String -> Int`. Our solution now looks like this:

```
filter (odd . length) ["abc","def","eh","123","hm","even"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go.

```
getOddOnes = filter . flip (foldr (const (. not)) id) $ False
```

Note: if you turn this in for your homework, you'd best be prepared to explain it!

Comment: While cute, your `isOddLength` part is needlessly complicated. A much more straitghtforward solution along the same lines would be `getOddOnes = filter $ foldr (const not) False`

Comment: @Cactus, there are reasons to prefer the left fold, I think, and this answer is intended to match the character of the question in a certain sense.